# does flex use frames?

Tags: frames, apache-flex

I'm looking into developing a game using the flex SDK instead of flash. I'm kind of not sure how to start.

One question I have - does Flex have a timeline like Flash, with frames etc? Is there a main/root timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Flex it is event-based and does not use a timeline for development. That is not to say that you cannot implement [timelines using state transitions](http://www.google.com/search?q=flex+state+transitions). I'm not sure what the performance would be like compared to Flash.